# Access javascript functions in included file of web page viewed in WebBrowser control

Tags: javascript, c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I understand how to use InvokeScript to call a JavaScript function on a web page viewed in the WebBrowser control.

But how do I invoke a javascript function in an included JS file on the web page?

Comment: Well you will need to inform what platform/programming language you are use. Yes it is a possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear but from my understanding you may be looking for

```
window[fnName](params);
```

Use this link as reference: https://ctrlq.org/code/20181-call-javascript-function-by-name?fbclid=IwAR2hb_7cSZOrJg0_ob7HdqbVKrMqLrPlU7uA8MKGVLgWsEMiBtko1_MvjX8